# Set SQL ordering by highest earnings/losses

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to use two kinds of ordering.

1. From the highest earnings
2. From the highest losses.

My database  [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcC2n.png)

| id | saldo | saldo_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 75,67 | 1 |
| 10 | 7 | 1 |
| 3 | 5,45 | 1 |
| 11 | 12,3 | 0 |
| 4 | 6,45 | 0 |

`saldo_type`:

- `1` = earnings
- `0` = losses

Expected result/output for sort by highest earnings:

| id | saldo | saldo_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 75,67 | 1 |
| 10 | 7 | 1 |
| 3 | 5,45 | 1 |
| 4 | 6,45 | 0 |
| 11 | 12,3 | 0 |

and by highest losses:

| id | saldo | saldo_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 12,3 | 0 |
| 4 | 6,45 | 0 |
| 3 | 5,45 | 1 |
| 10 | 7 | 1 |
| 7 | 75,67 | 1 |

So far I am stuck with such a code

```
SELECT id, saldo, saldo_type FROM `investitions`
ORDER BY
(CASE WHEN saldo_type = "1" THEN saldo END) DESC, 
(CASE WHEN saldo_type = "0" THEN saldo END) ASC
```

Expected result/output:

- [sort by highest earnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srLm0.png)
- [sort by highest losses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLGW1.png)

Comment: Shouldn't "saldo" be decimal? And which one is the expected result?

Comment: yes. Up to two decimal places (but not required)

Comment: but your data looks like its using comma instead for a decimal.. what is the datatype for `saldo`? `varchar`?

Comment: varchar(64) . I can't change it. Tried something like `SELECT FORMAT(saldo, 2)`

Comment: In that case, can you show us the expected result/output?

Comment: added two expected results/outputs

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to convert the losses to negative values then you will achieve your goal. In your case, try the following:

```
  SELECT id, saldo, saldo_type FROM `investitions`
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN saldo_type = "1" THEN saldo else -saldo END) desc
```

Comment: Looses should be [the other way](https://ibb.co/37Gxpvz)

Answer (score 0):

`Cast` saldo to `decimal`

```
SELECT id, saldo, saldo_type FROM `investitions`
ORDER BY saldo_type desc,cast(replace(saldo,',','.') as decimal(4,2)) desc -- sort by highest earnings
```

*Adjust the precision and scale according to your data*.

Comment: Values from `saldo_type=0` should be the other way. Sort by highest profit and  `saldo_type=0` means is loose. [preview](https://ibb.co/t2f9XNd)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. I was able to build a working query using a piece of each answer.

Query looks like this:

`` SELECT id, saldo, saldo_type FROM `investitions`  ORDER BY (CASE WHEN saldo_type = "1" THEN cast(replace(saldo,',','.') as decimal(12,2)) else -cast(replace(saldo,',','.') as decimal(12,2)) END) desc ``